# MySql server not starting

Tags: mysql

MySQL server is not starting after my machine was switched off without proper shut down. It showed the following message.

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

The log file contains the following. What is the root cause of the problem? How to recover from it?

```
131121 14:06:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
131121 14:11:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131121 14:11:42  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
131121 14:11:42  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 17 3015197486
131121 14:11:42  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Error: tried to read 1048576 bytes at offset 0 1048576.
InnoDB: Was only able to read 45056.
InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot read from file. OS error number 17.
131121 14:11:55  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139714140956640 in file os/os0file.c line 2299
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
08:41:55 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8384512
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338324 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29) [0x84c049]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x483) [0x6a0fa3]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x35d960f500]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x35d8e328a5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0x35d8e34085]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(os_aio_simulated_handle+0) [0x78fdb0]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(fil_io+0x1eb) [0x763a6b]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(trx_sys_doublewrite_init_or_restore_pages+0x194) [0x7d3b84]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(recv_scan_log_recs+0x524) [0x786ad4]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x78743a]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(recv_recovery_from_checkpoint_start+0x566) [0x787ca6]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(innobase_start_or_create_for_mysql+0x11e7) [0x7c3c17]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x72bacb]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(ha_initialize_handlerton(st_plugin_int*)+0x31) [0x694bd1]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x713b7b]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(plugin_init(int*, char**, int)+0x6e4) [0x715e74]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x5bd752]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(main+0x1b3) [0x5c0033]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x35d8e1ecdd]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x508ac9]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
131121 14:11:55 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Answer (score 3):

Kill the MySQl Process (or) re install it.

Answer (score 1):

try to follow this steps :

1. Revert any config changes you've made to the log file size and start
2. MySQL again. In your running MySQL: SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown=0;
3. Stop MySQL Make the configuration change to    the log file size
4. Delete both log files.
5. Start MySQL. It will    complain about the lack of log files, but it'll create them and all    will be well.

https://serverfault.com/questions/104014/innodb-error-log-file-ib-logfile0-is-of-different-size